# Is there any way to get the Firefox API’s

Tags: firefox

Is there any way to get firefox Api so that i can access them programatially

There any other method other than XPCom

Comment: What are you specifically aiming for?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question on SO: [Firefox API Access from my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025298/firefox-api-access-from-my-program)

By Matthew Lock:

> Using the [MozRepl Firefox extension](http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/)
>   you can read the current Firefox url
>   (among other things) from telnet. You
>   could then use AutoHotkey to access
>   telnet or via your own program and get
>   the current url.
>
> It seems you can also access the
>   Firefox url via DDE

If it doesn't answer your question I suggest trying to ask the question over at SO and be more specific about what you want to do, so they can help you more effective.